# Fixed scrolling menu inside a container

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's a demo of what I'm trying to do: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yisera/muze8kac/2/)

I need the menu to be where it currently starts at. Then move throughout the size of `c2`. However, when `c2` is reached, I need the menu to be positioned in the center of said div. When `c2` div is about to be scrolled up, entering div `c3`, I need the menu to stay fixed with a bottom margin on `c2`.

I have no idea how to accomplish this. 
Anyone knows where should I start digging at to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

That is Impossible, please read this [POSITION](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). This is example just stay to c1 but not to c3(to footer). That is just solve with Javascript/JQuery or another plugin javascript.

```css
#c1{
width:100%;
    height:100px;
  background:#ff0000;
}
#clearer{
  clear:both;
  }
#c3{
width:100%;
    height:200px;
  background:#ff0000;
}
}.wrapper {
    width:100%;
}
.container {
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:200px;
    background:#ccc;
    position:relative;
}
.sidebar-menu {
    position:fixed;
    width:50px;
    height:70px;
    margin-left:150px;
    border:0px solid #d6d6d6;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1">
    
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar-menu">
        <ul>
            <li>Option 1</li>
            <li>Option 2</li>
            <li>Option 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="c1">
    
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I'm trying to accomplish. the div needs to stay inside c2.

Comment: It stays fixed on the bottom. It needs to be able to scroll within c2 when the user scrolls.

Comment: the menu needs to stay within c2. When the user scrolls, the menu has to scroll on the viewport but ONLY scroll within c2. c1 is a header and c3 is a footer. the menu should only scroll on c2 which is the content of the website.

Comment: what you mean header and footer is fixed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74204/discussion-between-hsoto-and-wahyu-kodar).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stickyFloat](https://github.com/yairEO/stickyfloat) plugin for that. Do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/vsync/muze8kac/3/

```
// forces me to write code here...
```

Comment: It's not working properly. I load it, but the box just stays fixed.

Comment: well loading does nothing, you need to actually use it you know...it's like throwing vegetables in a pot and expecting a soup to appear.. you need to do some work for things to work. there is a README file and example page.

Comment: I meant the fiddle, not the actual JS plugin.